# Color specific edges and vertices in a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

How do I make only some edges and vertices a different color?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black,draw,minimum size=.2cm,inner sep=0pt},}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[main node] (1) {};
        \node[main node] (2) [below left = .75cm and .5cm of 1] {};
        \node[main node] (3) [below right = .75cm and .5cm of 1] {};

        \path[draw,thick]
        (1) edge node {} (2)
        (2) edge node {} (3)
        (3) edge node {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Answer (score 1):

Just add separate `color = your_color` elements to each node and/or edge you want, say,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black!20,draw,minimum size=.5cm,inner sep=0pt},}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black,draw,minimum size=.2cm,inner sep=0pt},}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[main node, color = red] (1) {};
    \node[main node] (2) [below left = .75cm and .5cm of 1] {};
    \node[main node] (3) [below right = .75cm and .5cm of 1] {};
    
    \path[draw,thick]
    (1) edge [color = blue] node {} (2)
    (2) edge node {} (3)
    (3) edge node {} (1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]